# Сборка автономного jar файла в Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли в `maven` собрать проект так, чтобы все сторонние библиотеки которые мы подключаем в `pom.xml` автоматически загружались в него и можно было бы спокойно запустить программу?

Знаю, что вроде могут помочь такие плагины как `maven-shade-plugin` и `maven-assembly-plugin`, но так как только начал изучать `maven` не могу понять, как они работают. Может есть у кого внятный пример?

Comment: Они просто сливают все файлы из всех jar'ников в один.Идея гиблая, т.к. у тебя могут потереться файлы ресурсов и мета-содержимое.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте плагин `assembly`:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass><название класса с методом main></mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

собирается это командой `mvn clean compile assembly:single`

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно, нужно подключить плагин.
В `pom.xml` добавляешь секцию `<build>`, в которую добавляешь секцию `<plugins>`, и туда копируешь [пример из документации](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
         <configuration>
            <archive>
               <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <mainClass>com.example.Start</mainClass>
               </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
               <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <finalName>TestJar</finalName>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                  <transformers>
                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.XmlAppendingTransformer" />
                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                     </transformer>
                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                     </transformer>
                  </transformers>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```