# Maven сборка и запуск jar фала

Tags: java, maven

У меня такая проблема при нажатии "maven install" maven сохраняет все зависимости в lib рябом с jar файлом и при этом генерирует maniffest где указывается запуск и пути к зависимостям(lib) но при указании пути он указывает имя пакетов

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>kz.wartemw.File</groupId>
        <artifactId>File</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>kz.wartemw.HelloWorld.Main</mainClass>
                        <packageName>kz.wartemw.HelloWorld</packageName>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/*</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

manifest.mh

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Package: kz.wartemw.HelloWorld
Built-By: wARTEMw
Class-Path: lib/org/joml/joml/1.9.4/joml-1.9.4.jar lib/kz/wartemw/File/File/12.07.17/File-12.07.17.jar lib/kz/wartemw/File/ThrowException/22.05.17/ThrowException-22.05.17.jar lib/kz/wartemw/File/ReadWriteBinary/22.05.17/ReadWriteBinary-22.05.17.jar lib/kz/wartemw/File/InputOutput/22.05.17/InputOutput-22.05.17.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_141
Main-Class: kz.wartemw.HelloWorld.Main
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скорей всего в устаревшем плагине

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>kz.wartemw.HelloWorld.Main</mainClass>
                <packageName>kz.wartemw.HelloWorld</packageName>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- это включит правильную версию плагина-->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archiver</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: извиняюсь. но эта * ни на что не влияет

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman все равно та же ошибка.(ели понизить версию jar то все работает но это хотелось б с новыми версиями что бы работало)

Comment: можно ли в это строчке добавить путь пакета зависимостей?
 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>

Comment: я прочитал что 1 статью как сохранить зависимости рядом с jar да бы в последствии запустить 1 jar файл и все. а что бы сохранить в сам jar что то не видел

Comment: Спасибо большое) версия 3.0.2 работает а вот остальные нет(

Comment: на самом деле проблема в версии maven-archiver. рекомендую собирать один большой jar.

Comment: "рекомендую собирать один большой jar" если не трудно можно статью по этому поводу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561659/215007